# substitution of minimization problem restrictions gives wrong answer

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Just got out of classes and the tutor couldn't find out what was wrong (though he solved it his way):

Find the points of the curve that is the intersection of equations

$$g^1: x^2 + y^2 -xy - z^2 = 1$$

$$g^2: x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

closest to the origin.

Well, that's
$$\min_{\left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb R^3} (x^2+y^2+z^2)\quad\text{st } g^1, g^2$$

Both restrictions have to be satisfied, than the restrictions reduces to $z^2 = -xy$. Well, if the restrictions are true, than the problem reduces to

$$\min_{\left(x, y, z\right)\in\mathbb R^3}( 1 - xy)$$

If $x$ is minimum, then it has to follow that $1-y =0$ and $1-x=0$, so I get $x=1$, $y=1$ and $z^2 = -1$, and that's a problem, cause z has to be a real value (and dont satisfy restrictions).

I understood Lagrange will give me the right results, but it's cumbersome to do with two restrictions. Any clues what I got wrong?

Comment: Why does it follow that e.g. $1-y=0$ ?

Comment: Be careful: you want to minimize $1-xy$ on $g_1\cap g_2$, not on the whole of $\Bbb{R}^3$! Which implies that you can't make $x$ and $y$ vary independently. Among these constraints, you found that $xy$ must be ${}\leqslant 0$ (since equal to $-z^2$).

Comment: @Leonardo derivative =0

Comment: @jpboucheron ok, but if i take the derivative it will give me x=1, y=1 in any situation

Comment: @MateusCardoso You can't use gradient = 0 as an optimality condition, if you also have contraints, that's the error. If you didn't have constraints, it would be a way to go. Do you know why?

Comment: @MateusCardoso It is correct that —at a point $M\in g_1\cap g_2$ where $OM$ is minimum— you must have both $xy=-z^2\leqslant0$ and $OM^2=1-xy$; thus $OM\geqslant1$. Moreover, at any $M\in g_1\cap g_2$ such that $xy=0$, you'll get $OM=1$…

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elementary (no differential calculus) solution: name $(P_\lambda)$ the horizontal plane having $z=\lambda$ as cartesian equation ($\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$).
Now consider any $M\in (g_1\cap g_2)\cap(P_\lambda)$. By Pythagoras' theorem the distance from $M$ to the origin is $OM=\sqrt{1+\lambda^2}\geqslant1$.

If you take $\lambda=0$, any $M\in g_1\cap g_2$ with $z=0$ is such that $\mathbf{OM=1}$, which thus achieves a minimum. Now if you report $z=0$ in the equation for $g_1$ and $g_2$, you easily find out that the solutions are given by $xy=0$ and $x^2+y^2=1$, thus $(x,y)=(\pm1,0)$ or $(0,\pm1)$.

Conversely it is immediately checked that the four points $(\pm1,0,0)$ and $(0,\pm1,0)$ belong to $g_1\cap g_2$.[image]

Comment: That's a nice way to solve it. Guess I more or less understood that if I add up the restrictions I doesn't necessarily incorporate than into the objective function, just get another necessary condition for z to satisfy... Can I ask what software did u use to get this image?

Comment: I used Geogebra and exported as a png with a high resolution to minimize pixelation, then reduced the size of the image. The surface $g_1$ has this parametrization: $\displaystyle\left(\cos u\sqrt{1+v^2}-\sin u\sqrt{\frac{1+v^2}{3}},\cos u\sqrt{1+v^2}+\sin u\sqrt{\frac{1+v^2}{3}}, v\right)$
for $(u,v)\in[0,2\pi\mathclose[\times\Bbb{R}$. This comes from its more simple equation with coordinates $(u,v,z)$ obtained after a rotation of angle $\pi/4$ around the $z$-axis.

Comment: As for $g_1\cap g_2$ (the red curves) they are made from 4 parts with these parametrizations: $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\sqrt3\cos t-\sin t}{\sqrt{2+4\cos^2t}},
\frac{\sqrt3\cos t+\sin t}{\sqrt{2+4\cos^2t}},
\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-4\cos^2t}{2+4\cos^2t}}\right)$ for $t\in[\frac\pi3,\frac{2\pi}3]\cup[-\frac{2\pi}3, -\frac\pi3]$.